# Creating new array of object in JavaScripts from another array

Tags: javascript

From an array of objects, I need to create another array of objects with some fields.

In my organicResults array I have the following items

I only need title, and url in the new array. I tried with the following

```js
 const organicResults = [ {
      title: '21 Excel Tips and Tricks to Boost Business | Process Street ...',
      url: 'https://www.process.st/excel-tips-and-tricks/',
      displayedUrl: 'www.process.st › excel-tips-and-tricks',
      description: 'Mar 10, 2017 — 90% of businesses use Excel in their operations. Learn these Excel tips and tricks to maximize your efficiency and automate your processes!',
      siteLinks: [],
      productInfo: {}
    },
    {
      title: 'Microsoft Excel Tips & Tricks | The Training Lady',
      url: 'https://www.thetraininglady.com/microsoft-excel/',
      displayedUrl: 'www.thetraininglady.com › microsoft-excel',
      description: 'When you are entering data in Excel you may want to ensure your data is entered in a consistent way. Maybe you have multiple people working on the same file ...',
      siteLinks: [],
      productInfo: {}
    },
    {
      title: 'What are the best Microsoft Excel tips according to you? - Quora',
      url: 'https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-Microsoft-Excel-tips-according-to-you',
      displayedUrl: 'www.quora.com › What-are-the-best-Microsoft-Excel-tips...',
      description: 'Originally Answered: What is the best microsoft excel tip according to you? Below is a listing of all the major shortcut keys usable in Microsoft Excel.64 answers',
      siteLinks: [],
      productInfo: {}
    },
]

    let sitesInfo = organicResults.map(result => ({
        title: result.title,
        url : result.url,
        description: result.description
        
    }))
    console.log(sitesInfo)
```

The output is null.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is fine. are you sure it's the whole code you're using?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. [Check this](https://codepen.io/syed_n_sakib/pen/LYRPOYM?editors=1111)

Comment: Actually I did a mistake. organicResults is an array of  array objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `return`

Insert this on the sitesInfo part

```
var sitesInfo = organicResults.map(results => {
var object = {
        title: result.title,
        url : result.url,
        description: result.description
    }
    return object;
});
console.log(sitesInfo)
```

Tell me if this works on you!:)

Comment: A return is not necessary. Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: The OP used implicit return in an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

Check your brackets for map method..

```
let sitesInfo = organicResults.map(result => {
  return {
    title: result.title,
    url : result.url,
    description: result.description
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It remains safer to use a regular function.

```js
let sitesInfo = organicResults.map(function(el) {
  return {title: el.title, url: el.url, description: el.description}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Let me show a shorter version where you declare desired properties:

```
let sitesInfo = organicResults.map(({title, url, description}) => 
    ({title, url ,description}))
```

An example:

```js
const organicResults = [ {
      title: '21 Excel Tips and Tricks to Boost Business | Process Street ...',
      url: 'https://www.process.st/excel-tips-and-tricks/',
      displayedUrl: 'www.process.st › excel-tips-and-tricks',
      description: 'Mar 10, 2017 — 90% of businesses use Excel in their operations. Learn these Excel tips and tricks to maximize your efficiency and automate your processes!',
      siteLinks: [],
      productInfo: {}
    },
    {
      title: 'Microsoft Excel Tips & Tricks | The Training Lady',
      url: 'https://www.thetraininglady.com/microsoft-excel/',
      displayedUrl: 'www.thetraininglady.com › microsoft-excel',
      description: 'When you are entering data in Excel you may want to ensure your data is entered in a consistent way. Maybe you have multiple people working on the same file ...',
      siteLinks: [],
      productInfo: {}
    },
    {
      title: 'What are the best Microsoft Excel tips according to you? - Quora',
      url: 'https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-Microsoft-Excel-tips-according-to-you',
      displayedUrl: 'www.quora.com › What-are-the-best-Microsoft-Excel-tips...',
      description: 'Originally Answered: What is the best microsoft excel tip according to you? Below is a listing of all the major shortcut keys usable in Microsoft Excel.64 answers',
      siteLinks: [],
      productInfo: {}
    },
]

    let sitesInfo = organicResults.map(({title, url, description}) => 
        ({title, url , description}))
    console.log(sitesInfo)
```